# WebView displaying Local Video Sprite Kit - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview, sprite-kit

I'm trying to display a local video using a WebView in an SKScene. Here's my code:

```
   import UIKit
   import SpriteKit
        
    class SwiftScene: SKScene, UIWebViewDelegate {
         
            var startY: CGFloat = 0.0
            var lastY: CGFloat = 0.0
            var moveableArea = SKNode()
            
            
            var webview = UIWebView()
            
            override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
                
                // set position & add scrolling/moveable node to screen
                moveableArea.position = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
                self.addChild(moveableArea)
         
        //moveableArea.addChild(Sprites Here)
        
                webview.delegate = self
                webview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width * 0.85, height: self.size.height / 4)
                let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/niallkehoe1/Desktop/xcode/Swift/Test-801/Test-801/SwiftAnnounced.mov")
                webview.loadHTMLString("<iframe width = \"\(self.webview.frame.width) \" height = \" \(self.webview.frame.height)\" src+ \"\(fileURL)\"> </iframe>", baseURL: nil)
                
                webview.center = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
                
                view.addSubview(webview)
            }
            
      
           override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
               
            for touch in touches {
                let location = touch.location(in: self)
        
                startY = location.y
                lastY = location.y
                
            }
        
        }
    
        override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        for touch in touches {
            let location = (touch as AnyObject).location(in: self)
            // set the new location of touch
            var currentY = location.y
            
            // Set Top and Bottom scroll distances, measured in screenlengths
            var topLimit:CGFloat = 0.0
            var bottomLimit:CGFloat = 0.6
            
            // Set scrolling speed - Higher number is faster speed
            var scrollSpeed:CGFloat = 1.0
            
            // calculate distance moved since last touch registered and add it to current position
            var newY = moveableArea.position.y + ((currentY - lastY)*scrollSpeed)
            
            // perform checks to see if new position will be over the limits, otherwise set as new position
            if newY < self.size.height*(-topLimit) {
                moveableArea.position = CGPoint(x: moveableArea.position.x, y: self.size.height*(-topLimit))
            }
            else if newY > self.size.height*bottomLimit {
                moveableArea.position = CGPoint(x: moveableArea.position.x, y: self.size.height*bottomLimit)
            }
            else {
                moveableArea.position = CGPoint(x: moveableArea.position.x, y: newY)
            }
            
            // Set new last location for next time
            lastY = currentY
        }
        
    }

  }
```

But this is what appears:

[image: Screenshot]

The video won't display. The touches Moved is being used for a kind of a scroll view action. I add `SKSpriteNode` and `SKLabelNode` by using.

```
moveableArea.addChild(Node Here)
```

but this doesn't work with a UIWebView so how should I add it?

Note: This might be because I don't have access to `viewDidAppear()` so I used `DidMove(to view: SKView)`

Comment: There is an SKVideoNode so you do not need to use a web view,  also, are you sure you are properly loading a video file? Finally, your web view should be basing its size on the UIView, not the SKScene.  Results will vary across devices if you are not using resize fill properly (If you are using any other scale mode and setting a scene size, you are doing it wrong)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I used SKVideoNode and I've discovered that you were right and it wasn't able to find the file. I used this code:

Comment: Image here : https://postimg.org/image/84t58zc5p/ . But I can't understand why this isn't finding the image. My file name is **Swift - Announced.mp4**  @Knight0fDragon .